# Does PHPWord work with zend-escaper 2.5?

Tags: phpword

I tried to install PHPWord as part of a Drupal project:

```
$ composer require phpoffice/phpword
...
Problem 1
- Installation request for phpoffice/phpword ^0.13.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpword[v0.13.0].
- Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-escaper 2.5.2
- Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-escaper 2.5.2
...
```

Downgrading `zendframework/zend-escaper` is not an option. Is there a way to get PHPWord to work with the current version?

Oddly, the `master` branch declares `"zendframework/zend-escaper": "^2.4",` in `composer.json`, but the `develop` branch declares `"zendframework/zend-escaper": "^2.2",`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the change from the develop branch has been promoted to the master branch.
you can either use the dev-master version, or wait for version 0.14 to be published, which will be any day now.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that `composer require phpoffice/phpword:dev-master` works with a composer-managed Drupal 8 project. I am not yet sure that the package will do what I want, but at least I am past the hurdle of getting it installed.

Comment: FYI, version 0.14.0 was released, so no need to point to the master branch anymore.